# Laravel job with database driver returns Class not found

Tags: laravel, class, jobs, pdflib

I am using a Laravel job which handles specific registration confirmations via mail.

In the `handle()` function of the job I am referring to another class' static function (`TicketController`) which generates a PDF:

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->ticket = TicketController::createPdf($this->customer);

    Mail::to($this->customer->email)->send(new CustomerAccepted($this->customer, $this->ticket));
}
```

If I run this job via `sync` driver everything is just working fine. But with `database` I always get the error

`class 'PDFlib' not found`

Of course the class is implemented in my `TicketController` and I also tried implementing it directly into my job class.

I also tried restarting the queue worker several times but I always get the same result when running with `database`.

EDIT:

`TicketController.php`:

```
use App\Customer;
use PDFlib;

class TicketController extends Controller
{
    public function createPdf(Customer $customer) 
    {
        $p = new PDFlib();

        $p->set_option("errorpolicy=return");
        $p->set_option("stringformat=utf8");
        $p->set_option("searchpath={" . resource_path() . "assets/fonts" . "}");
        $p->set_option("spotcolorlookup=false");

        if ($p->begin_document(storage_path('app/xy.pdf'), "") == 0) {
            echo ("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
            exit(1);
        }
        // Loading template and filling with content

        $p->end_page_ext("");
        $p->end_document("");

        return storage_path('app/xy.pdf');
    }
}
```

EDIT #2

I added the complete `PDFlib` function directly to the `handle()` of the job but still getting the same error `class 'PDFlib' not found`.

EDIT #3

Just realized that running the driver `database` locally and listen to queues with `php artisan queue:listen` is working perfectly fine.

I am running the application on Laravel Forge and also `database` driver. Tried to set up the queue with daemon worker and without but neither setting works.

Comment: Could we see the TicketController?

Comment: Yeah, we're going to need to see where you're actually using PDFlib. Given that it doesn't work in a queued job but works in an unqueued version, I'd bet it's something about being unable to serialize a PDFlib instance properly.

Comment: I added `TicketController`

Comment: @MangoD So, a couple things. First, `createPdf` doesn't return anything. If that bit's just not shown, I suspect what's happening is Laravel is serializing the `$p` object, but that PDFlib doesn't support that. Instead of setting it to `$this->ticket`, try generating it on-the-fly in the `handle()` function.

Comment: @ceejayoz Oh right. I added the returned value. It is just a path to the created file from PDFlib.
Okay, I will try to add the function directly in the `handle()` method.

Comment: @ceejayoz Edited my question. Had no luck with adding the `PDFlib` method to the job.